# CSRF Spring Security через Ajax (JSON)

Tags: java, ajax, spring-security, upload, csrf

У меня проблема с CSRF и Spring Security. Когда я посылаю форму я получаю статус 302

[image: ошибка]

**Я сделал так:**

```
auth.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

**другими словами:**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity auth) throws Exception {
    auth.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
            auth
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/static/**","/webjars/**","/registration").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/user").access("hasAuthority('USER')")
                    .antMatchers("/admin","/add").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .permitAll();
}
```

**Мапинг:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<User> update(@RequestBody User user){
    userMapper.findByName(user.getUsername());

    if (userMapper.findByName(user.getUsername())!=null){
        user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
        userMapper.addUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }else
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

**Форма:**

```
<form id="registration">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}" />
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="password">
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password">

<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

как реализовать Spring Security и CSRF для Ajax (JSON). Если есть туториал или пример, буду благодарен.

Comment: Гоубо говоря - вставляем функцию в скрипт отправки запросов $ajaxSetup.preSend(finction(xhr) { headers: "CSRF-TOKEN:" + cookie_value; xhrFields: true });

Comment: контроллер и конфиг не менять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить мета теги

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
<!-- ... -->
</head>
<!-- ... -->
```

и так же в сам файл javascripta

```
$(function () {
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});
});
```

и вставить токен в отправные данные. Есть еще пару способов, но помог мне этот.

Нашел ответ, по этой [ссылке](https://habr.com/post/264641/) если кому либо понадобится

Answer (score 0):

Для ajax запросов можно убрать csrf на сервере.

```
auth.csrf().disabled().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/static/**","/webjars/**","/registration").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/user").access("hasAuthority('USER')")
                    .antMatchers("/admin","/add").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .permitAll();
```